# ARCGIS for javascript : TPK data retrieval

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Is it possible to retrieve the data from a tpk?Means, is there a way to embed some information in tpk like address, region etc. and retrieve that information by means of querying

Comment: Please let me know why the downvotes are ,so that i can make the corrections in the question

Answer (score 0):

No, this wouldn't be possible.

Firstly according to the [ESRI Documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006600000457000000) Tile Packages are solely for storing raster tiles, when displayed these tiles would show a user a map image but could not be queried interactively to identify or search for addresses / regions.

Additionally tile packages would not be practically accessible to web applications designed with the ArcGIS Javascript API.  Tile packages are zipped file systems containing a large number of images, the usual way of making these tiles available to an application would be through a map service.

I would recommend for this type of functionality you view the [examples on querying map services](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/query_hover.html) as a demonstration of what is available with the API.